# WPF Scrollviewer won't scroll up

Tags: wpf, scrollview

I have the following (simplified) xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="143*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="135*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl Margin="12,29" Name="tabControl1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
            <ScrollViewer Height="440" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="872" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Height="440" Name="grid1" Width="851" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
...
```

My problem is the scroll won't show up. What should I change ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content inside the `ScrollViewer` is smaller than the `ScrollViewer` itself. The `ScrollViewer` is used for being able to use scrollbars to show content that is larger than the area the `ScrollViewer` takes up.